# app crash whil run both collection view and table view same time .Crash :fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

i have one collection view which will scroll horizontally.And in that collection view each cell click - i have to load the respective data in table view.So i placed my table view under collection view.

**crash report :**

```
fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
```

Here is my code :

```
class HomeDiscoverViewController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {

    @IBOutlet var BTCollectionView: UICollectionView!

    @IBOutlet var DLTableView: UITableView!

    var BTdata = [BTData]()

    var Dealsdata = [DealsData]()

    override func viewDidLoad()
    {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        ListBusinessTypes()
    }
// Values from Api for Business Types
    func ListBusinessTypes()
    {
        let token = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().valueForKey("access_token") as! String

        let headers = ["x-access-token": token]

        let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string: "someurl")!,
                                          cachePolicy: .UseProtocolCachePolicy,
                                          timeoutInterval: 10.0)
        request.HTTPMethod = "GET"
        request.allHTTPHeaderFields = headers

        let session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()
        let dataTask = session.dataTaskWithRequest(request, completionHandler: { (data, response, error) -> Void in
            if (error != nil)
            {
                print(error)

                let ErrorAlert = UIAlertController(title: "Error", message: "Problem with internet connectivity or server, please try after some time", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)

                // add an action (button)
                ErrorAlert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: nil))

                // show the alert
                self.presentViewController(ErrorAlert, animated: true, completion: nil)
            }
            else
            {
                if let json = (try? NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: [])) as? Dictionary<String,AnyObject>
                {
                    let success = json["success"] as? Int

                    if(success == 1)
                    {
                        if let typeValues = json["data"] as? [NSDictionary]
                        {
                            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(),{

                                for item in typeValues
                                {
                                    self.BTdata.append(BTData(json:item))
                                }
                            })
                        }
                        self.BTCollectionView.reloadData()
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        let message = json["message"] as? String

                        print(message)

                        let ServerAlert = UIAlertController(title: "Error", message: message, preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)

                        // add an action (button)
                        ServerAlert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: nil))

                        // show the alert
                        self.presentViewController(ServerAlert, animated: true, completion: nil)
                    }
                }
            }
        })

        dataTask.resume()
    }

    // values from Api For Deals
    func ListDeals(BTId:String)
    {
        let token = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().valueForKey("access_token") as! String

        let headers = [
            "cache-control": "no-cache",
            "postman-token": "1befe4c6-ec7c-ccb3-f537-97307f451807"
        ]

        let StringURL = "someurl"+token

        let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string: StringURL)!,
                                          cachePolicy: .UseProtocolCachePolicy,
                                          timeoutInterval: 10.0)
        request.HTTPMethod = "GET"
        request.allHTTPHeaderFields = headers

        let session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()
        let dataTask = session.dataTaskWithRequest(request, completionHandler: { (data, response, error) -> Void in
            if (error != nil)
            {
                print(error)
            }
            else
            {
                if let json = (try? NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: [])) as? Dictionary<String,AnyObject>
                {
                    let success = json["success"] as? Int

                    if(success == 1)
                    {
                        if let DealsValues = json["data"] as? [NSDictionary]
                        {
                            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(),{

                                for item  in DealsValues
                                {
                                    let itemObj = item as? Dictionary<String,AnyObject>

                                    let b_type = itemObj!["business_type"] as? String

                                    if(b_type == BTId)
                                    {
                                        self.Dealsdata.append(DealsData(json:item))
                                    }
                                }
                                self.DLTableView.reloadData()
                            })
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        let message = json["message"] as? String

                        print(message)

                        let ServerAlert = UIAlertController(title: "Error", message: message, preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)

                        // add an action (button)
                        ServerAlert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: nil))

                        // show the alert
                        self.presentViewController(ServerAlert, animated: true, completion: nil)
                    }

                }

            }
        })

        dataTask.resume()
    }

    // Mark : Collection View Delegate and Datasource(Business Type)
    func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int
    {
        return BTdata.count
    }

    func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell
    {
        let cell: DDLCollectionCell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("BTCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! DDLCollectionCell
        cell.BTName.text = BTdata[indexPath.row].BTNames
        return cell
    }

    func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath)
    {
        ListDeals(BTdata[indexPath.row].BTIds!)
    }



    // Mark : Table View Delegate and Datasource(Deals)

    // count of search value and row value that are displaying
    func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int
    {
        return self.Dealsdata.count
    }

    // number of rows
    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int
    {
        return 1
    }


    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
    {
        let cell:DealsListTableCell = self.DLTableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell") as! DealsListTableCell
        cell.DealName.text = Dealsdata[indexPath.row].DealNames
        cell.DealExpiryDate.text = Dealsdata[indexPath.row].DealAddresses
        return cell
    }
```

I am getting that fatel error here:

```
self.BTCollectionView.reloadData()
```

Under `ListBusinessTypes()` method.I added all delegate and datasource.But Don't know what i am missing.Please help me out.

Thanks.!!

Comment: outlet `BTCollectionView ` is connected?

Comment: Yes, its connected

Answer (score 0):

This may happen either for two reason:

> 1. You may not given the right "Reuse Identifier" ( in your case: either 'BTCell' or 'cell' ) in the cell class xib of either table view or collection view.
> 2. If mistakenly you are setting "nil" text to label.
>
> Generally this type of error comes when your variable is set to nil,
>   but your code is expecting it to not be nil ( try to figure out this by using the error breakpoints).

Hope this will help you to resolve!

Comment: i first checked this two thing only.Ever thing fine.But i don't know my its giving this error in hat collection view name?If i add collection view name .delegate & data source = self also.Then if i run .Again i am getting this crash in that data source of collection view

Comment: so, is it happening only with collection view?

Comment: yes.I delete my table view and i checked.That time also same error in collection view

Comment: check your all variables once again, because this type of error comes when your variable is set to nil, but your code is expecting it to not be nil.

Answer (score 0):

[image: add Exception Breakpoint from breakpoint navigator.]

It will lead you to the problem.